# AngularJS hide element if empty

Tags: angularjs

I need a way to hide a parent element if the element inside of it is empty using AngularJS.

Would this be a custom directive type issue or is there a way to put the logic into something like `ng-show` or `ng-hide`?

```
<div class="item"> <!-- item should be hidden -->
    <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how `div` inside will be empty? by some element, property..?

Comment: A combination of `ng-show="check"` and `$scope.check = $scope.parent.child.isEmpty()` could work if it's an object; depends on your logic

Answer (score 0):

I would assume the inside div would have some data from the scope displayed? If the data is an empty string of null, then you can check that with ng-hide in the parent. Something like the below perhaps?

```
<div ng-hide='myData == null' class="item"> <!-- item should be hidden -->
    <div class="inside">{{myData}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is extremely reasonable. Unfortunately the code inside the 'inside' div is injected with pure javascript because I HAVE to use element.appendChild() to get a webrtcmulticonnection video element to display inside there. I couldn't figure out how to get angular to append the elements from a scoped array. If I just use {{scopearray.data[0]}} , it the element/stream doesn't display.